# I'm getting an #Error message in my Access join queries, but I'm not sure why

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm attempting to merge two separate sets of data. Between the two sets of data, some entries may be duplicates.

Table 1:

```
 Common Field A | Field 1 | Field 2
 ---------------------------------
       a            a1        a2
       b            b1        b2
```

Table 2:

```
  Common Field B | Field 3 | Field 4
 ---------------------------------
       c            c1        c2
       a            a1        a2
```

I did a union query on the common field to get:

```
  Common Field 
 ---------------
       a
       b
       c
```

Now I did 2 joins. One join between the union query and table 1, and one join between the union query and table 2. Basically each join is done so that all the entries of the union query will be listed, and the rows where the common fields from the tables matches the union query entries will be listed. After doing this I created a query with all the columns (keeping in mind the above two joins). Here is what I expected:

```
 Common Field | Common Field A | Common Field B | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       a               a                a            a1        a2        a1        a2
       b               b                             b1        b2
       c                                c                                c1        c2
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
 Common Field | Common Field A | Common Field B | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       a               a                a            a1        a2        a1        a2
       b               b              #Error         b1        b2
       c             #Error             c                                c1        c2
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the #Error signs, and I'm just as confused as to why I'm only getting them for the Common Field entries. If anything, I would have expected to at least get them like this:

```
 Common Field | Common Field A | Common Field B | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       a               a                a            a1        a2        a1        a2
       b               b              #Error         b1        b2      #Error    #Error
       c             #Error             c          #Error    #Error      c1        c2
```

Is there any way to get rid of them? I've tried using IIF(IsError(....)) but that hasn't worked. I found a couple of attempts online where people have tried to get to get rid of #Error message but were unable to solve it. I know it's better to get to the root of the problem, but at this point I'm okay with just getting rid of the #Error message itself. Any ideas on how I should approach this?

EDIT: Here's some example SQL:

```
SELECT qryUnion.CommonField, tbl1.CommonFieldA, tbl2.CommonFieldB, tbl1.Field1, tbl1.Field2, tbl2.Field3, tbl2.Field4 
FROM tbl2 RIGHT JOIN ( tbl1 RIGHT JOIN qryUnion ON tbl1.CommonFieldA = qryUnion.CommonField) ON tbl2.CommonFieldB = qryUnion.CommonField;
```

EDIT2: Here's the SQL for the join if that's important:

```
SELECT tbl1.CommonFieldA FROM tbl1 UNION tbl2.CommonFieldB FROM tbl2
```

Comment: While your logic has been posted, please supply the SQL that you're using.  That is the only definitive way to determine what is happening.

Comment: Hi Remou and RobB, thanks for the responses! As requested, I posted my SQL, I hope that helps.

Comment: @KryptKeeper: What version of MS Access?  I just tried your example in Access 2010 and it works just fine without any `#Error`.  You could try using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead, or [the equivalent](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm) if your version of MS Access doesn't support it.

Comment: I just tried in MS Access 2003 as well, and it works perfect as well (note that you have a typo in your UNION query: should be `SELECT tbl1.CommonFieldA as CommonField FROM tbl1 UNION SELECT tbl2.CommonFieldB FROM tbl2;
`).  Are you sure you don't have corruption in your database?  Try a compact and repair and see if it goes away, or try copying your data into a fresh database.  Is it possible that your contrived example is too simple to represent the actual scenario where you are seeing the errors?  **Edit:**  Tried Access 97, still works just fine.

Comment: I agree with the two comments, it works, once the change to UNION is made.

Comment: Here's some example code for a simulated full outer join if you want to give that a try and see if you get different results: http://pastie.org/4564325

Comment: Sorry about the long delay, thanks for everyone's responses. mellamokb, you're right about missing the "SELECT" part, I think I just typed that out incorrectly but I'm pretty sure I typed it correctly in the actual SQL so I don't think that's the issue. I'm using Access 2010 and since it's working for you I'm thinking you're right and my example is a little bit too simple. I don't have access to the file right now so I'll try to think of a better example when I do in a couple of hours but to give an idea, I'll type my post as another comment because I'm running out of room here:

Comment: My tables 1 and 2 are actually queries. My original tables 1 and 2 would have had 4 fields each. In the queries, I merged two fields together to make a concatenated field, which became my "Common Field". My union query is just a list of all these concatenated fields. If we say that CommonFieldA is made up of fields PartA and PartB, then the #Error message I'm getting is showing up under CommonFieldA (as shown in the main post) but also in fields PartA and PartB. I'm not sure how much that helps, but I'll try to post more in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've done this in a query window, given the displays of #error, and the syntax of your query.

Create a new query, get rid of the add table window, put it into SQL view, then put this logic in it:

```
select c.unique, a.commonfieldA, b.commonfieldB, a.field1, a.field2, b.field3, b.field4
from (
    select distinct u as unique from (
        select commonfieldA as u from tbl1 
        union all
        select commonfieldB as u from tbl2
    ) combined ) c 
    left join tbl1 a on c.unique = a.commonfieldA
    left join tbl2 b on c.unique = b.commonfieldB
```

This should work. I dont use the Union syntax you've got, and instead select distinct values from union-all'd composite (subquery "combined"). Left join means that the data must exist in the table on the left of the join condition (ie c, being the table which defined prior to the declaration of either tbl1 or tbl2) but data may or may not exist in the table on the right.

I would put your problem down to the syntax access generates for you, in it's attempt to understand what you're trying to do: That it showed "#Error" says to me that it didnt understand.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it in a couple of hours when I have access to the file.